# Convergence of $p$-series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I've been given a few problems of the form:

> Find all values of $p$ such that the series converges:
>
> $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(k)}{k^p}$
>
> $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(c+k)^p}$ with $c > 0$

Naively, I'd assume that both series converge for $p > 1$ (following from that any $p$-series converges for $p > 1$). However, it's obviously (?) not that simple.

How does one approach such a problem?

Comment: Is anything stated about $c$?

Comment: @Clayton Apologies, I meant to write $c>0$.

Comment: Your "naive" intuition is correct ! Try to compare these series with "well-known" series.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pointers.

For the first problem, you can immediately observe that $p > 1$ for the series to converge, but is this tight? To answer this question, you may want to proceed by contradiction and ask yourself the question "if for some $ p \geq 1 + \epsilon > 1$, the series did not converge, what would this imply about the $p$-series with $p = 1 + \epsilon / 2 > 0$"? I'll flesh this out with an example: suppose, say this series did not converge for $p = 1.01$. Then for sufficiently large $k$, say $k \geq k_0$, we have that $k^{0.005} > \ln k$, so
$$\sum_{k = k_0}^\infty \frac{k^{0.005}}{k^{1.01}} = \sum_{k = k_0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^{1.005}} > \sum_{k = k_0}^\infty \frac{\ln k}{k^{1.01}} = \infty$$
so this would imply that the $p$ series with $p = 1.005$ does not converge, which we know is not true. The key idea is that $\ln k$ grows slower than any polynomial in $k$. I'll let you fill in the details for the general case.

For the second problem, we can immediately see that it converges for $p > 1$ by the direct comparison test, but now we have to ask if it could converge for $p \leq 1$. We claim that it does not converge for $p = 1$, and as a result does not converge for $p \leq 1$. To see this, note that every term of the series is at least $1 / (\lceil c \rceil + k)$. From here, can you see that this series is always divergent? For an explicit example, consider $c = 5.073$. Then the series
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{c + k} \geq \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{6 + k} = \frac 1 7 + \frac 1 8 + \frac 1 9 + \cdots$$
Is it clear why this series must be divergent?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For the first series (which is a *Bertrand's series*), use the integral test.

For the second series, use *asymptotic equivalence*:
$$(c+k)^p\sim_{k\to\infty}k^p, \quad\text{ whence }\quad\frac1{(c+k)^p}\sim_{k\to\infty}\frac1{k^p}.$$